# EditText with TextWatcher slow and I do not see the bar in the text

Tags: android, textwatcher

Practically in a EditText I implemented a Listener TextWatcher, the problem is, if I click inside the text, the bar remains stationary in the usual spot, even if i delete some letters .. why? .. Maybe because in afterTextChanged I change the text color?

code:

```
private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            setTextColor(arg0);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                    int after) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                    int count) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }


             };

    private CharSequence setTextColor(Editable editable) {
                editable.clearSpans();

                if (editable.length() == 0) {
                    return editable;
                }


                    color(Patterns.HTML_OPEN_TAGS, editable);
                    color(Patterns.HTML_CLOSE_TAGS, editable);
                    color(Patterns.HTML_ATTRS, editable);
                    color(Patterns.GENERAL_STRINGS, editable);
                    color(Patterns.XML_COMMENTS, editable);

  return editable;
            }

 private void color(Pattern pattern,
                               Editable editable) {
                int color = 0;
                if (pattern.equals(Patterns.HTML_OPEN_TAGS)
                        || pattern.equals(Patterns.HTML_CLOSE_TAGS)
                        || pattern.equals(Patterns.GENERAL_KEYWORDS)
                    //|| pattern.equals(CSS_STYLE_NAME)
                        ) {
                    color = Patterns.COLOR_KEYWORD;
                } else if (pattern.equals(Patterns.HTML_ATTRS)
                        || pattern.equals(Patterns.CSS_ATTRS)) {
                    color = Patterns.COLOR_ATTR;
                } else if (pattern.equals(Patterns.CSS_ATTR_VALUE)) {
                    color = Patterns.COLOR_ATTR_VALUE;
                } else if (pattern.equals(Patterns.XML_COMMENTS)
                        || pattern.equals(Patterns.GENERAL_COMMENTS)) {
                    color = Patterns.COLOR_COMMENT;
                } else if (pattern.equals(
                        Patterns.GENERAL_STRINGS)) {
                    color = Patterns.COLOR_STRING;
                } else if (pattern.equals(Patterns.NUMBERS)) {
                    color = Patterns.COLOR_NUMBER;
                }

                for (final Matcher m =
                             pattern.matcher(editable);
                     m.find(); ) {
                    editable.setSpan(
                            new ForegroundColorSpan(color),
                            m.start(),
                            m.end(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
```

Comment: would actually have to see what exactly it is you are doing in setTextColor

Comment: nothing changed for me

Comment: now you see the change?

Comment: so now, what does color do? besides that, setTextColor return an editable, but your not doing anything to it in your afterTextChanged method. so im guessing your color(x,y)-method is flooding the uiThread, which results in an unresponsive cursor?

Comment: i add the color method..so i think that, but how i can fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

> call setTextColor(arg0);  on onTextChanged